# Accessing object values by variables

Tags: javascript

```
$obj = new Object();
$obj.surname = "smith";

$field_name = "surname";

alert($obj.$field_name); //error!!
```

Wth? How do I do this with js? I need to access all values in an object within a foreach but I can't manage to access obj proprerties by reference!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$obj[$field_name]` will do. It's the same with the literal keys: you may use `object['id']` as well as `object.id` - the latter is shorter, though. )

Answer (score 1):

you can access each property by entering the name of the property as a key  .

> JavaScript automatically creates a associative array for each object
>   where the keys are properties names and values are there value .

So instead of `$obj.$field_name` use `$obj[$field_name]`
because $obj.feild_name is like $obj."surname"

check this [Objects as associative arrays](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/associative.html)